# How to copy data between collections in firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have two collections verification and users.
I want data of a document from verification and copy it to users.

My firestore database is like :

Verification :

[image]

Users :

[image]

```
void copyData() {
    final databaseReference = Firestore.instance;
    var docref = databaseReference.collection('verification').document("1604051013");
    docref.get().then((doc) {
      if (doc.exists) {
        print("Document Data " + doc.data.toString());
        databaseReference.collection("users").document("1").setData({
          'userName': doc['userName'],
        });
        print(doc['userName']);
      } else {
        print("Error in firestore");
      }
    });
  }
```

Above code prints the values fine but does not set the values in users collection.

Comment: You're not checking the result of `setData` for errors, so if something goes wrong, you would never know.  It is probably failing because you're trying to create the same document `users/1` repeatedly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to access document data on the document snapshot, in this line:

```
'userName': doc['userName'],
```

Should be:

```
'userName': doc.data['userName'],
```

Final code, also with renamed var to reinforce it's a snapshot and not data:

```
void copyData() {
    final databaseReference = Firestore.instance;
    var docref = databaseReference.collection('verification').document("1604051013");
    docref.get().then((docSnapshot) {
      if (docSnapshot.exists) {
        print("Document Data " + docSnapshot.data.toString());
        databaseReference.collection("users").document("1").setData({
          'userName': docSnapshot.data['userName'],
        });
        print(docSnapshot.data['userName']);
      } else {
        print("Error in firestore");
      }
    });
  }
```